# mercurial hgwebdir error with basicauth in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, mercurial, http-basic-authentication

I'm having kind of a strange error that I'm trying to track down.  I was trying to setup mercurial on my home server this weekend.  I seem to have it running up to the point where I'm trying to get repositories published correctly.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with Mercurial version 1.4.3.

I followed the [hgwebdir guide](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) and everything seems to work great, I can pull and push my local repositories.  Then I tried to add basic auth changing

```
ScriptAliasMatch     ^/hg(.*)      /var/hg/hgwebdir.cgi$1
<Directory "/var/hg">
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
ScriptAliasMatch     ^/hg(.*)      /var/hg/hgwebdir.cgi$1
<Directory "/var/hg">
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName hgwebdir
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/httpd/users
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This works exactly as I'd expect it to when I navigate to the directory via my web browser, but when I `hg push` get a long section repeating of

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 855, in http_error_401
  url, req, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 833, in http_error_auth_reqed
  return self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 843, in retry_http_basic_auth
  return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
```

followed by

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 249, in do_open
  self._start_transaction(h, req)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/url.py", line 419, in _start_transaction
  return keepalive.HTTPHandler._start_transaction(self, h, req)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 342, in _start_transaction
  h.endheaders()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 904, in endheaders
  self._send_output()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 776, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/url.py", line 247, in _sendfile
  connection.send(self, data)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 519, in safesend
  self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/url.py", line 273, in connect
  keepalive.HTTPConnection.connect(self)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I'm a bit at a loss on this one.  I'm really not sure why adding the authorization seems to work fine via my web browser but throw these errors from `hg`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

got a response from the great folks on the Mercurial IRC channel.  This was addressed in [Issue2255](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2255). I made their changes and it works like a charm.

Comment: Please accept this answer so that your question doesn't show up on the "unanswered questions" list.